# WCF receiving requests from multiple clients

Tags: wcf

I have written a WCF service that received XML requests from multiple clients, Process the request, save data to database and returned the response back as xml string.
All client applications will make a synchronous call to WCF Service ( will send request and wait for response, once the response is received send next request).

End point details : 
    binding : basicHttpBinding
Operation Contract  :

```
[OperationContract]
string ReceiveMessage(string xmlString)
```

Connection Through : Channel Factory

I want to do the load test for this WCF service, to make sure if it handles requests from multiple clients and process successfully without any bottleneck.
Do I need to set service behavior (Instance mode and concurrency mode) to receive requests from multiple clients. if yes please suggest the correct configuration ?

Per call
per session

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default WCF instance & concurrency are exactly what you need 99% of the time, especially if you're hosting the service in IIS. There are a few edge case where it might be worth changing the default values (singleton & service controlled multithreading) but generally just save yourself some gray hairs and use the defaults.

If you really want to understand what these two settings do, read this [old but still good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx) on the topics. Did I mention you want to leave the default setting alone? :-)

Comment: its hosted in IIS, so i think its good to go with default configuration ...Thanks for quick response.